# Replacing PrimaryKey in AppSync Dynamo Schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

this is my schema:

```
type Session @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public},{ allow: owner }, { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }]) {
  sessionId: ID! @primaryKey
  numPeoplePresent: Int
  procedures: Procedures @hasOne
  notes: String
  cattle: [Cow] @manyToMany(relationName: "CowSessions")
}
```

this is the error I am seeing:

```
errors: [Amplify.GraphQLError(message: "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field \'id\' in type \'Session\' is undefined @ \'onCreateSession/id\'", locations: nil, path: nil, extensions: nil)]
Recovery suggestion: The list of GraphQLError contains service-specific messages
```

I thought having sessionId as a primary key would replace the need for id field but am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with the if it ain't broke, don't fix it approach and just went back to using regular "id" instead of the "sessionId".

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the sessionId type to string and it should work.

type Session @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public},{ allow: owner }, { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }]) {
sessionId: String! @primaryKey
numPeoplePresent: Int
procedures: Procedures @hasOne
notes: String
cattle: [Cow] @manyToMany(relationName: "CowSessions")
}